# Which version of TeXMaker should I install for OS X El Capitan?

Tags: texmaker, mactex, mac

I looked at the TeXMaker website, and it lists two 64 bit binaries for OS X: `MacOsx Lion/Mountain Lion/Maverick` and `MacOsx >=10.6`. I wasn't sure which of these to download, as they seem to conflict (Lion, Mountain lion, and Mavericks are all greater than 10.6). The Lion/Mountain Lion/Mavericks distribution seems to work better with a retina resolution, but since El Capitan wasn't on that list, I wasn't sure if I could use it. Both distributions seem to work.

Comment: I think the difference between the two options is 32 bit vs 64 bit.

Comment: @erik No, these are both 64 bit. There is an older 32 bit version below them, but I omitted that because I know I need one of the two 64 bit versions.

Comment: Then it must be the different UI framework. The newer version (Mavericks, etc.) uses Qt5 instead of Qt4.

Comment: @erik does that mean that I should use the mavericks,etc. one for el capitan, even though its not listed on there?

Comment: Welcome! @JoeBrooks Probably there isn't one for El Capitan yet. That means you will likely have to do some manual configuration to get it working. Pick the one for the newest version of OS X i.e. if Mountain Lion or whatever is higher than 10.6, try the one for Mountain Lion etc. as it is likely to be closer to what you have than the other. (I'm assuming here that EC is more like its recent predecessors than it is like its less recent ancestors.)